# " swapper " vs " init " performing the cpu idle loop

Tags: linux, operating-system

As known ,  in OS there is an idle task that gets scheduled to run " when there’s no other work "

```
void cpu_idle (void)
{
    /* endless idle loop with no priority at all */

    while (1) {
        void (*idle)(void) = pm_idle;
        if (!idle)
            idle = default_idle;
        if (!current->need_resched)
            idle();
        schedule();
        check_pgt_cache();
    }
}
```

This code is representing the " cpu idle loop " which is performed by the swapper task.

The question is : why the init task cannot do this loop instead ?

Comment: Because `init` is a real program.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Do you mean " real time process " ?

Comment: No, I mean a userspace process versus a kernel process.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and how does this affect us?

Comment: @noodlez040: What if you run an `init` that *doesn't* run an idle loop?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I guess my question was why do we need BOTH init and idle instead of having 1 process that does both their duties?

Comment: @noodlez040: The init process doesn't actually *have* any duties per se. Any arbitrary executable can be used as the first process. Sure, it has to do certain things if we want the system to behave in a specific way, but there's no reason you can't run e.g. bash as the init process and change how the whole system works.